Change block icon z-order
I have defined an agent type and added some shape objects (rectangles) to the definition and tagged them as "Icon".

When I place an instance of my agent on main, I successfully obtain the rectangle however the z-order of this icon on main is above all other model generated agents so if I (for example) move a vehicle across the icon the image of the vehicle passes underneath the icon image.  I want to change the z-order of the icon so that when my vehicle passes across the icon, it passes over the top of it.
Attempting to change the z-order of the shape that represents the icon does not have any affect and indeed I cannot even remove the icon from the runtime presentation.
presentation.remove(rectangle); // does not remove the icon image from main presentation
presentation.insert(0, rectangle); // does nothing!

main.presentation.remove(rectangle); // does not remove the icon image from main presentation
main.presentation.insert(0, rectangle); // does nothing!

However if I want to change the colour of my rectangle or hide it altogether at run-time then this works fine:
rectangle.setFillColor(gainsboro);  // works perfectly
rectangle.setVisible(false); // works perfectly

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can manipulate the z-order of the agent icon to play nicely with my other agent animations?

PS: Only use the "anylogic" tag, that suffices :)

Do not turn it into an icon, icons are not meant to be used for animation.
Drag in your rectangles suffices. AnyLogic automatically creates the animation on the parent agent if you embed your agent into it (if not, click the population/agent icon and click the "show presentation" button).
Icons are not part of the normal animation that can be stacked via the z-ordering. But if you untick it, you will be able to manually or programmatically change the z-order.
PS: Only use "Icon" if you want your agent population to not be the little red circle but some other visual, but typically you only use this to develop libraries...)

Thanks Ben,  I found an obscure comment in AnyLogic help that says "The shapes making up an icon do not belong to any level." So that goes a long way to explaining why it is not possible to change the z-order.
So I am happy to use just a normal animation element but when I place my agent onto main it puts the animation element at 0,0 rather than where I put the block on the page.  Do you have any idea how I can get the location of the block - or do you think we are pushing up against the same problem ^?

Also, do you have any idea how I'd go about making my own block similar to say the "Service with Lines" block in the Pedestrian library which actually puts animation elements onto main right where you place it.

pls always ask new questions in new issues, SOF does not work like a forum but is a Q&A place, see some tips: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow
